# How can I find out the Response code returned from a $resource request?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
 $resource('/api/:et/:id', { et: $scope.data.entityType })
                        .delete({ id: entityId }, deleteSuccess, error)
                        .$promise.finally(last);
```

How can I find out what response code is returned if the the $resource completes with a success or error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of errors your *error* handler will be called with a single parameter *(httpResponse)*, so you can look up the HTTP status in its *status* property:

```
function error(httpResponse) {
    var status = httpResponse.status;
}
```

Success callbacks are called with two parameters: *(value, httpHeaders)*. *httpHeaders* is a function returning an object with all HTTP response headers if invoked without parameters, or the value of a single header if invoked with a header name:

```
function deleteSuccess(value, httpHeaders) {
    var allHeaders = httpHeaders(); // all headers
    var contentType = httpHeaders('content-type'); // response content type
}
```

(see the docs for [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) for more details).